# Google Forms API method forms.watches.create will not work with service account

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-forms, google-forms-api

I am attempting to use the forms.watches.create method for Google Forms API. It seems like I am running into a common issue that others are also experiencing where you cannot successfully use the method with a Service Account. I am attempting to use Okta Workflows to initiate the watch on a form. Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can use this method without creating a full on web app? I prefer to keep it simple with an HTTP request from Okta if possible.

- Created a Google Cloud project and service account inside the project
- Activated the Forms API
- Added the service account to domain wide delegation in admin with the proper scope required in the Forms API documentation (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.responses.readonly)
- Created a pub/sub topic in the same Google Cloud project and added forms-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com as a pub/sub publisher as instructed in the API docs
- Ensured that both the delegated user and the service account were added to the form as editors
- Receiving a 400 error when running the request: "Project does not have necessary OAuth permissions from authorizing user."

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]